# Fancybox works in Firefox locally but does not work on server

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I incorporated Fancybox to the following URL:

http://www.radiocraft.ca/Corvette/corvette.htm

It works locally on my computer in both IE9 and Firefox 18, however when loaded on my server Firefox opens photos in a new tab. IE9 works fine on the server.

Something is amiss and I do not see what.

Could someone please point out what specifically has to be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

The linking to the jquery.fancybox.pack.js and jquery.fancybox.css files are incorrect, you are currently setting them as

```
file://///USER-PC/Users/user/Documents/My Webs/My Webs4/radiocraft.ca/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
file://///USER-PC/Users/user/Documents/My Webs/My Webs4/radiocraft.ca/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
```

These are local address to your computer, they should set to the server address instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Thank you.You pointed in right diresction, although I had to play with the links to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. You pointed into right direction, although I had to play with the links to make it work. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad it help, you can also accept the answer so the community knows the question has been resolved